# regex for certain characters and rules

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex to ensure a given string only contains these 13 certain characters/rules. I am having a bit of trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

Allowed Characters:

1. a-z
2. A-Z
3. 0-9
4. ! (Exclamation point)
5. - (Hyphen)
6. _ (Underscore)
7. . (Period)
8. * (Asterisk)
9. ' (Single Quote)
10. ( (Open parenthesis)
11. ) (Close parenthesis)
12. (No consecutive spaces)
13. *. (CANNOT end with a period)

So Far I have this

/^[+\-0-9().!-_*' ]+$/g

But not getting expected results. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Sorry first time posting here. Here are some test cases(JS). Second one should not pass because it has consecutive spaces and ends with period.:

```
 let testOne = "Testing Regex - 2021 Th*i)s_On(e_pa!'ss.es.end";
 let testTwo ="Testing Regex - 2021 Th*i)s_On(e_pa!'ss.es.end  but 
 shouldn't.";
 
 testOne.match(/^[+\-\w().!-_*' ]+$/g);
 testTwo.match(/^[+\-\w().!-_*' ]+$/g);
```

Comment: "But not getting expected results." Please explain the expected results, show them and the input for which they should occur. Also show the results you currently get and describe how they are different.

Comment: All letters are missing. You should allow the shortcut `\w` to have 0-9, a-z and A-Z included.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your regex does not allow for Latin letters: you didn't list them.
- Your regex allows for some additional characters (including `$`, `#` and `%`) because of `!-*`, which specifies a *range*.
- There is no provision for not allowing more than a single space.
- There is no provision for not allowing a dot as last character
- The `g` modifier has little purpose when you have end-of-string markers requiring that a match will always match the *whole* input.

From your regular expression it seems you also require that the input has at least 1 character.

Taken all that together, we get this:

`/^(?!.*?  )(?!.*?\.$)[\w+\-().!*' ]+$/`

Comment: So far this(second solution) is working properly. I should have been more intelligible in describing some of the rules such as consecutive spaces. I will run more tests and confirm your solution shortly. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the other interpretation from my answer then ,-)

Comment: I believe it is less costly. If greedy, the dot will first match *all* characters up to the end of the input, and then it will have to backtrack to find a place to continue the match (like for matching the double space). If lazy, the scan will be forward only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^(?!.*  )[\w!()\-*'\s.]+[\w!()\-*'\s]$
```

https://regex101.com/r/kTcJUN/3

And if you don't want to allow space character at the end of string then:

```
^(?!.*  )[\w!()\-*'\s.]+[\w!()\-*']$
```

**Explanation:**

`(?!.*  )` - Exclude double space in string

`\w` - any word character. Matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].

`!` - literally `!`

`(` - literally `(`

`)` - literally `)`

`-` - literally `-`

`*` - literally `*`

`'` - literally `'`

`\s` - space character

`.` - literally `.`

`+` - quantifier. Matches between one and unlimited times.

`[\w!()\-*'\s]` - Allow a single character from the list. Putting this just before `$` (end of line) makes this character last in string.

Comment: Almost, IMO you are missing that this would now match anything other than a dot at the end, e.g: `test%` would match.

Comment: @JvdV Well spotted. Thanks. I modified the answer.